# DropdownList and Textbox not callling SelectedIndex/Text Changed on first postback in IE and FF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this is a problem that's been asked a few times before, but having had a look around I can't seem to find an answer that works for me.

I have a VB.NET page with 2 textboxes (set to show dates using JQuery), a dropdownlist and a datagrid.

Both textboxes and the dropdownlist are set to fire events, if they're changed, to update the datagrid.

Generally this works fine with one exception; when I change the value of either the textboxes or the dropdownlist after the initial page loading it often doesn't fire the event, the postback is set to false and the dropdownlist value is cleared; this doesn't happen in Chrome and is less frequent in Firefox than in IE.

I've  tried the following:

I've set autopostback=true on all items

Tried adding an extra item, which isn't enabled, to the dropdownlist

Moved the boxes/List outside the update panel

Set ViewStateMode=Enabled

Tried adding a hidden field which is set to Request.Form(ddlDropdownList.UniqueNumber) and comparing it to Request.Form(ddlDropdownList.UniqueNumber) in the page load as a way to fire the event (the suggestion says to use Request.Forms, but this isn't coming up as an option on intellisense?)

All of these solutions either don't work, cause other issues, or I'm not doing them right (Which could certainly be the case)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, it's been a while since I've done web forms, but I do recall there being a problem with listboxes where I had to check if the page was not on a postback when populating it.

So basically in your page loading method, check to see if the page is *not* a postback before initalising it. I found that even though I selected a new item, it was resetting the list back to it's default state.

This may or may not help you, but I thought it was worth at least mentioning it.

Comment: I've got the BuildDropDownList() inside an "if Not IsPostBack", this is being hit on that first selectedindexchange as ispostback is set as false (just the first time though). I also moved it into a clause that checked if the textbox was populated (as they don't seem to be being reset) and when I do this the dropdownlist isn't populated at all.